# How do I pass back an object from a method in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback, debugging, models

I have the following in my Omniauth callback:

```
@user = User.find_for_linked_in_oauth(env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)
```

I expect either way to get a user object.  Her is the User method.  Right now, I am testing the case where it *cannot* find an existing User because it hasn't been created yet:

```
   def self.find_for_linked_in_oauth(omniauth_hash, signed_in_resource=nil)
     debugger
     #omniauth_hash is a hash passed in from env["omniauth_hash"] by callback controller
     linkedin_uid = omniauth_hash['uid']
       debugger
       if user = User.find_by_linkedin_uid(linkedin_uid)
          debugger 
          user
       else # Create an user with a stub password.
         #redirect to a page to ask for an email address and display information
         #User.create!(:email => "token@email.com", :linkedin_uid => linkedin_uid, :password     => Devise.friendly_token[0,20]) 
         user = User.new
         user.first_name = omniauth_hash['user_info']['first_name']
         user.last_name = omniauth_hash['user_info']['last_name']
         user.linkedin_uid = linkedin_uid

         user
         debugger
      end
```

Currently, with debugger, I get back '1' as the value for p @user.

I want the newly created user object to be passed back so I can then ask the current user to add additional information before saving it.

Why am I not getting the newly created user as the value of @user?

Comment: What's the debugger variable/method for? That's what ruby is returning in that else block, whatever the value of debugger is. Put `user` under that instead of above and it will return the User.

Comment: @scragz -- I think you're right -- now I am getting a multi_json error so can't test it though....any ideas? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change places `user` and `debugger` so it will return `user`

```
 19   def self.find_for_linked_in_oauth(omniauth_hash, signed_in_resource=nil)
 20     debugger
 21     #omniauth_hash is a hash passed in from env["omniauth_hash"] by callback controller
 22     linkedin_uid = omniauth_hash['uid']
 23       debugger
 24       if user = User.find_by_linkedin_uid(linkedin_uid)
 25          debugger 
 26          user
 27       else # Create an user with a stub password.
 28         #redirect to a page to ask for an email address and display information
 29         #User.create!(:email => "token@email.com", :linkedin_uid => linkedin_uid, :password     => Devise.friendly_token[0,20]) 
 30         user = User.new
 31         user.first_name = omniauth_hash['user_info']['first_name']
 32         user.last_name = omniauth_hash['user_info']['last_name']
 33         user.linkedin_uid = linkedin_uid
 34 
 36         debugger
 35         user
 37      end
```

Comment: @floor, you're right, that makes sense...I can't test it though -- I am getting an error regarding "multi_json" -- had to post that an awaiting help to even get this working... :( any suggestions ?)

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the debugger statement is messing things. Try exchanging statements like :

```
debugger
user
```

in the end of your function.

Comment: I am using debugger to exit so I can see what the value is....will I still be able to do that?

Comment: No, you need to return the value that you want. If you need to check it, better do it in your view using <%= debug @user %>

Comment: @spoyros, thanks -- I can't test your suggestion, I am getting a new, unrelated error regarding multi_json?